# How to use line comments to separate and annotate the sections of the more than 2 programs in SAS?

Tags: sas

How to use line comments to separate and annotate the sections of the more than 2 programs in one editor in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

A line comment in SAS is made like so:

```
*this is a line comment;
```

Starts with an asterisk (`*`) and ends with a semicolon.

So you might use that to document your code by preceding sections of code with line comments that explain what the code is doing, what parameters are expected for a macro, or what attributes datasets might contain.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Joe has said, SAS will ignore the line beginning with " * " until it reaches the first semicolon ";".

Alternatively, You could also use /* and */ (no spaces between * and /) to comment out a line or a block of text.

```
/*

text that will be ignored by SAS and appear as comments

*/
```

All the statements and code between /* and */ will be ignored when you execute your program.